# Get wget output to a variable

Tags: scripts, wget

How can I do it? I am trying it like this
RESULT=`wget $URL`

P.S. - Also any recommended sources for learning shell scripting?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about:

```
RESULT="`wget -qO- http://example.com`"
echo $RESULT
```

Edit: Yeah, that works.

Comment: Why another dash after `-qO`?

Comment: `O` tells it to output somewhere, `-` tells `O` to output it to the current stream. And `q` tells wget not to include any of its "Connecting to xxx..." information.

Comment: What I meant was that when `-q` is the quiet switch & `-O` is used for giving the name to file where we want the output to be saved. From what I have been reading, we can write multiple switches together if all of them don't require arguments. So `-qO` makes sense but then what does the last dash do?

Comment: It's `-O`'s argument. It tells it where to write the output of the download (in this case: back to the current stream).

Comment: Getting invalid option 0 and -

Comment: "If `-` is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion. "

Answer (score 28):

The preferred way would be

```
result=$(wget -qO- http://example.com)
echo "$result"
```

(lowercase variable name, `$()` instead of ``` `` ``` and quoted expansion of the result variable).

For shell scripting with bash and/or POSIX sh, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is the guide to read. And there's a lot more useful resources on that wiki, and on http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/. I'm afraid most other resources on shell scripting are garbage, so it's best to stick with those two.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Can you explain it a bit what's wrong with quotes here?

Comment: @Ashfame This explains the main reason of why you should always quote expansions: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments

Comment: Thanks! I have bookmarked the resources. I will learn from there. :)

Comment: Why are most other resources on shell scripting garbage?

Comment: @Koveras how should I know? People probably read the ABS guide and then decide they'll share their newfound knowledge with the world with yet another crappy tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what about them is of inferior quality, specifically.

Comment: @Koveras Well the most common problems I see is guides teaching broken code like ``for i in `ls`; do `` and `ls | grep .mp3`. And not teaching how to quote parameter expansions and command substitutions. Basically the first two [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)

Answer (score 0):

in WGET (for WINDOWS BATCH), there is like this:

```
OtherApplication -arg1 -arg2 > temp.txt
set /p MyVariable=<temp.txt
```